# tabularray - How to center both text and images

Tags: graphics, vertical-alignment, tabularray

My goal is to have all text and images centered horizontally and vertically in their cells. Which options should I give to `tabularray` to achieve this?

I am getting close, but the vertical centering is still not working:

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{scrreprt} 
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
    \centering
    \begin{tblr}{ | Q[c,3.5cm] | Q[c,3.5cm] | Q[c,3.5cm] | Q[c,3.5cm] | }
    \hline
    \SetCell[c=2]{} Heading 1 & & \SetCell[c=2]{} Heading 2 & \\
    \hline

    Lorem Ipsum & \includegraphics[height=1.6cm]{example-image} & Lorem Ipsum & \includegraphics[height=1.6cm]{example-image} \\ 
    \hline 
    Lorem Ipsum & \includegraphics[height=1.6cm]{example-image} & Lorem Ipsum & \includegraphics[height=1.6cm]{example-image} \\ 
    \hline
    Lorem Ipsum & \includegraphics[height=1.6cm]{example-image} & Lorem Ipsum & \includegraphics[height=1.6cm]{example-image} \\ 
    \hline 
    \end{tblr}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I do not insist on using `tabularray` - if there is a more adquate package/macro, please let me know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to move image baseline to its vertical center. For example by use of the `adjustbox` package:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{fullpage}

\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
    \centering
    \begin{tblr}{ | Q[c,3.5cm] | Q[c,3.5cm] | Q[c,3.5cm] | Q[c,3.5cm] | }
    \hline
    \SetCell[c=2]{} Heading 1 & & \SetCell[c=2]{} Heading 2 & \\
    \hline

    Lorem Ipsum & \includegraphics[height=1.6cm, valign=c]{example-image} & Lorem Ipsum & \includegraphics[height=1.6cm, valign=c]{example-image} \\
    \hline
    Lorem Ipsum & \includegraphics[height=1.6cm, valign=c]{example-image} & Lorem Ipsum & \includegraphics[height=1.6cm, valign=c]{example-image} \\
    \hline
    Lorem Ipsum & \includegraphics[height=1.6cm, valign=c]{example-image} & Lorem Ipsum & \includegraphics[height=1.6cm, valign=c]{example-image} \\
    \hline
    \end{tblr}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Here's one possibility using `graphbox`, which provides the `align` option to `\includegraphics`. I also switched to the current syntax of `tabularray`.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphbox}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
    \centering
    \begin{tblr}{
        colspec={Q[c,3.5cm]Q[c,3.5cm]Q[c,3.5cm]Q[c,3.5cm]},
        vlines,
        hlines,
        cell{1}{1,3}={c=2}{c},
    }
    Heading 1 & & Heading 2 & \\
    Lorem Ipsum & \includegraphics[height=1.6cm, align=m]{example-image} & Lorem Ipsum & \includegraphics[height=1.6cm, align=m]{example-image} \\ 
    Lorem Ipsum & \includegraphics[height=1.6cm, align=m]{example-image} & Lorem Ipsum & \includegraphics[height=1.6cm, align=m]{example-image} \\ 
    Lorem Ipsum & \includegraphics[height=1.6cm, align=m]{example-image} & Lorem Ipsum & \includegraphics[height=1.6cm, align=m]{example-image} \\ 
    \end{tblr}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: table]

Comment: Minor nitpick:  `align=m` seems to place the text slightly above the horizontal centerline. Changing to `align=c` looks better, IMO.